# CSS Scroll Box Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a scroll box using the "overflow" property in CSS however writing mulitple lines of text will cause the box to require additional left and right scrolling, I am trying to find a way to format the text or box so that the scrolling towards the bottom can be eliminated. I was able to get hide the bar itself but the text was still out of view.

Answer (score 0):

try remplacing `overflow:auto;` by `overflow-y: auto;` in your css ;)
it will make the scroll only vertical and not horizontal and vertical

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/WYCu2/8/
http://jsfiddle.net/WYCu2/8/show

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.content {
    position:relative;
    width:990px;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid gray;
}
.scroll {
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:400px;
}
```